# If a $2×2$ matrix has determinant $0$, why is its rank $1$ if $\vec 0$ is not in the domain?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, matrix-rank, jacobian

Let $A=\mathbf{J}\left(\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2},\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}\right)$, then the $\text{det}A=0$ for every point in $\mathbb{R}^2$ except $\vec 0$ where the function is undefined. Its rank can only be $0$ or $1$. At first I thought its rank was $0$ since it sent the basis vectors to $\vec 0$, but I suspect this may be wrong since $A$ is not linear (given that it changes with its arguments). The book says its rank is $1$ because its domain does not include the zero vector, but why does not including a zero vector imply the rank of the transformation is $1$?

Comment: the determinant of $A$ is not dependant on a point

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo but why does that imply its rank is $1$?

Comment: The rank is the dimension of the range, so the only matrix with rank $0$ is the zero matrix.

Comment: By the way, the rank in the case is in the sense of [differential topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(differential_topology)).  In general, the rank of a smooth map can vary from point to point, but there is a nice class of maps with constant rank.

Comment: @SpamIAm so the fact that the domain does not include the zero vector imply that $A \ne \mathbf 0$ and therefore it cannot have rank $0$?

Comment: I don't think the fact that the domain of the function is $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{(0,0\}$ has anything to do with it.  As I said, the only matrix of rank $0$ is the zero matrix.  Is there a point $(x,y)$ such that $A(x,y) = 0$?  If not, then the rank is $1$.